# Deprecation Notice: Class App\Http\Controllers\tagsController does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-7, psr-4

whenever i try to update my composer, or require a file from composer for my laravel project, i always get this:

Deprecation Notice: Class App\Http\Controllers\tagsController located in C:/Users/User/Documents/To-do-app/cms-project/blog/app\Http\Controllers\TagsController.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. It will not autoload anymore in Composer v2.0. in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassMapGenerator.php:201

i have looked closely at the tagsController and can't seems to spot the error.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\Tags\CreateTagsRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\Tags\UpdateTagsRequest;
use App\Tag;

class tagsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        return view('tags.index')->with('tags', Tag::all());

    }
}
```

i have checked the tagscontroller class and cannot seems to know where the issue lies.
P.S: i did not output the whole class here because i do not think it is really necessary to do so.

Comment: My guess would be that it starts with a lower case character. `tagsController` instead of `TagsController`.

Comment: `TagsController` is not `tagsController` ... match the case of the classname to the filename

Comment: question answered. Thank you @MagnusEriksson and others for the swift response